# Cannot get BufferedWriter to write out all the data from a file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have this function that iterates through a directory and is supposed to read in each file and write it out to a generated HTML file. The BufferedReader should be reading in properly because I use the same thing elsewhere. However, in the generated HTML file, I am only getting every other line of data from the original files in the directory. Here is the method that should accomplish this:

```
// Tests to see if "File" is actually a directory or file,
// then writes out the file if it passes the test
void writeFiles(File directory, BufferedWriter bw) {
    try{
        for( File file : directory.listFiles() ){
            if(!file.isDirectory()) {//is a file lets read it
                FileInputStream filestream = new FileInputStream(file);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(filestream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String buff = new String();
                bw.write("<b>////////////////////////////////</b><br/>");
                bw.write("<b>File: " + file.getName() + "</b><br/>");
                bw.write("<b>////////////////////////////////</b><br/>");
                while((buff=br.readLine()) != null){
                    bw.write(br.readLine() + "<br/>");
                }
                bw.write("`<br/>`");
                bw.write("`<br/>`");

           }else {//will make it a recursive search
               writeFiles(file, bw);
           }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
        fnf.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I apologize for the bad formatting of the code in the question. Because of the HTML, the preformatted text won't let my code appear properly. However, I definitely think I have a File I/O issue in my code. Does anyone have any idea whether it is the BufferedReader or BufferedWriter? Thanks.

Comment: You should declare the String buff like this: `String buff;`. You shouldn't initialize it, since it is always overwritten here: `(buff = br.readLine())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
while((buff=br.readLine()) != null){
  bw.write(br.readLine() + "<br/>");
}
```

You are calling br.readLine() twice.

Try:

```
while((buff=br.readLine()) != null){
  bw.write(buff + "<br/>");
}
```